# Magento restore can't access admin

Tags: magento

I have recently restored out magento site to a backup version. When I try to access /admin I get the following error thrown.

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/monkey/observer" already exists
```

Trace:

```
#0 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/monk...', false)
#2 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1335): Mage::getSingleton('monkey/observer')
#3 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(292): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#6 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/page_...', 'head')
#7 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/page_...', 'head')
#8 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#9 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#10 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#11 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#12 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#13 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php(81): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#14 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction()
#15 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#16 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/energize/public_html/shop/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

I get this error if I try to access the front end.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function isLockExists() on a non-object in /home/energize/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php on line 257
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the server having this error.

Access the server via SSH and run the following commands in your magento directory.

```
php -f shell/compiler.php disable
php -f shell/compiler.php clear
php -f shell/compiler.php compile
```

Comment: Ok i have done the above, but still the exact same message appears.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways help you login access Magento Admin:

1- Please try to login via FTP or Cpanel and go to */app/etc/modules*
and disable modules of Ebizmarts (change value from **true** to **false** in code *XML* or rename file)

2 -Go to */includes/config.php* and comment out both lines.

Note: please clear cache (session if needed) then.

Comment: Thank-you for responding, There are no files that reference Ebizmarts under that location on our webserver.

Comment: Please try rename **/var** folder on root directory. i think this will help. If you you cant fix it. Please pm me, i can fix it thelp you. Im a freelancer(Magento developer). Thanks !